# ht access url direction want to remove a word and also add a directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to do a redirect for an old site product url to the new one.

old - http://oldsite.co.uk/productname-p-100.html (p-100 refers to the product id)

new - https://newsite.com/product/productname

I am trying to use wildcards for this.The issue is I am having problems removing
the -p and the 2 or 3 digits following the product name & the html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but most likely this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([-_\w]+)-p-\d+\.html$ https://example.com/product/$1 [R=301]
```

That rule will work likewise in the http servers (virtual) host configuration and in dynamic configuration files ("`.htaccess` style files").

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I will try to explain a bit better. I have added the old  .co.uk domain name to my hosting companies name server & created a ht access file under old name directory for forwarding my old categories to new categories and it works fine. The reason is I set up individual rules for it. However in terms of the products as I have more than 600 products it is not possible. That's why I am looking for a solution. Thanks for your help and will give it a go.

Comment: @Nomad Sure, I figured so much, makes sense. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I think it wasn't too clear. What I am trying to do is this. I am having problems removing the -p and the 2 or 3 digits following the p  in the old url & also the html.

Comment: @Nomad Sure. Got that. That is what the code in this answer should do for you.

Comment: Sorry, I posted it under the ht access of oldsite.co.uk and it doesn't work.  The only one works is this                                                      
  RedirectMatch 301 /(.*).html https://newsite.com/product/$1

Comment: The only one works is this                                                      
  RedirectMatch 301 /(.*).html https://newsite.com/product/$1

Comment: However, it doesn't remove the p-*** at the end though

Comment: @Nomad "it doesn't work" has never helped anyone anywhere at any time to solve an issue. You need to be precise: what does that mean _exactly_? What happens? Do you get an error? Is it redirecting to the wrong location? Does nothing happen at all?

Comment: Question: are you _really_ sure that the rewriting module is actually loaded into the http server and that the interpretation of dynamic configuration files is enabled at all and allows to rewrite? Do you get any entries in your http servers error log file?

Comment: The requested URL /product-p-641.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. this what it was saying with the rewrite engine on. my hosting assured me that the rewrite module is always on

Comment: That is the error message you see in the browser. You have to take a look at the http servers error log file to gain more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. Just to confirm do I place this file under the old servers' ht access or the new? if it is new then do I leave the old redirect as it is in the old server file?

Comment: It belongs in the old domains documents location, since you want to react on requests to _that_ domain and rewrite _to_ your new domain.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I tried it again and not working. when it changed it back to the rule i mentioned at least it was taking me to the new site. If it is any help this is the rule used to create the original urls 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-([0-9]+).html$ product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

Comment: Please give a real world example of an existing "old" URL.

Comment: Ah, ok. I modified the rule pattern slightly. Do you have any other "non word characters" besides the dash (`-`) in the product names?

Comment: the new one will be 
https://newsite.com/product/bicycle-chain-bracelet . please note digits 226 vary sometimes it is 2 digit like 22

Comment: Sure, the `\d+` matches _any_ sequence if digits. If you want it more precise you can change it to `\d{2,3}` to match only numbers composed out of 2 or 3 digits.

Comment: Wow, You have done it. yes, it works now. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Hey, glad I could be of help, you are welcome. We learn from that _again_ how important it is to be precise in the question. Always a good idea to give some real world example.